# How to get azure market place publisher id and product information?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sendgrid, azure-marketplace

I am using SendGrid with Azure and have a ARM template that deploys SendGridAccount to Azure. However while deploying it fails saying that I need to accept market place terms for SendGrid

I got the powershell that accepts the market place terms.
`Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher "SendGrid" -Product "SendGrid Email Delivery" -Name "Free" | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept`

However I am not able to find the correct publisher id, product and offer names for the SendGrid. How can I find this information?

Comment: can you share the template?

Comment: Part that deploys SendGrid Account looks like this `{
      "name": "[variables('sendgrid_Account_Name')]",
      "type": "Sendgrid.Email/accounts",
      "location": "[parameters('Applocation')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "plan": {
        "name": "free",
        "publisher": "Sendgrid",
        "product": "sendgrid_azure",
        "promotionCode": ""
      },
      "properties": {
        "password": "[parameters('sendgrid_Account_Password')]",
        "acceptMarketingEmails": false,
        "email": "[parameters('sendgrid_Account_Email')]"
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the template gives it away:

```
publisher: Sendgrid
product: sendgrid_azure
name: free
```

so the command would be:

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher SendGrid -Product sendgrid_azure -Name Free
```

Comment: ughh...don't know how I missed that one. Thanks